# An annoying SQL deadlock

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

Consider the following setup:

```
create table Tabl
    (
    ClustInd int,
    NonClustInd int,
    NonClustInd_Addon int,
    OtherCol int
    )
    create clustered index CLI on Tabl (ClustInd)
    create nonclustered index NCLI on Tabl (NonClustInd) include(NonClustInd_Addon)
    go

    --just generating & inserting 2^4*4 = 65536 records:
    ;with h(a) as (select 0 union all select 0), 
    h1(a) as (select h1.a from h h1, h h2, h h3, h h4),
    h2(a) as (select h1.a from h1, h1 h2, h1 h3, h1 h4),
    r(a) as (select row_number() over (order by a) from h2)
    insert into Tabl(ClustInd,  NonClustInd, NonClustInd_Addon, OtherCol)
    select a, a*10 - 10000, 60 + a*5, a*3 from r
```

Now if you run this in one session:

```
    declare @g int
    while 1 = 1
    --Using "OtherCol" to force the NCLI -> CLI -> Tbl lookup
    select @g = OtherCol from Tabl where NonClustInd = 477210
```

and this in another:

```
    while 1 = 1 
    update Tabl
    --Updating NonClustInd_Addon to force the updating of the NCLI and CLI indexes
    set NonClustInd_Addon = case when NonClustInd_Addon = 1 then 2 else 1 end
    where NonClustInd = 477210
```

the "select" statement will dead lock with the update statement.

The reason why they deadlock is because the select statement first locks the "NCLI" index and then the "CLI" index. And the update statement - first the "CLI" index, then "NCLI". Obviously this eventually causes a deadlock.

Is there a way to beat this deadlock? Maybe there's a way to control the order in which indices are locked (because if, for example, SQL locked CLI and then NCLI for both update and select, this deadlock would have never arisen).
Thanks.

PS: additional info:

During the update the following locks exist:
[image: Update]

During the select:

[image: Select]

Seconds before the deadlock:

[image: Deadlock]

Comment: Is this a hypothetical setup? Or are you running into this issue with a real case? Could you provide us with some more 'real' code or examples then? IMO the indexes not only get locked, but the whole table has a shared lock when you start the 1st session. Session 2 will try to get an exclusive lock but fails to do so until the shared lock is released, which in this example is never.

Comment: No, not hypothetical, I've run into this on a production environment.
Obviously I had to rename the tables/columns/indices and ommit certain columns that don't participate in the select/update, and I used "while 1=1" to imitate the high rate of updates/selects that occur on production. 
But the rest is real.

Comment: Have you checked DMVs (like `sys.dm_tran_locks` and `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks`) to see what exactly is being locked?

Comment: Yep, I've updated my question and added info on the locks.

Comment: Well, this is 'normal' behaviour when updating rows in a table. Have you looked at `ISOLATION LEVELS` to reduce the chance of deadlocking? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Use snapshot isolation or `read committed snapshot`. This is usually easy to implement and the negative consequences are often by far worth it. It simplifies your life by taking read-only transactions completely out of the equation. They don't lock or block anymore.

If you can do that, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

By using the 'NOLOCK',we can avoid this deadlock...Try Like this..

```
declare @g int

while 1 = 1

select @g = OtherCol from Tabl WITH(NOLOCK) where NonClustInd = 477210
```

Answer (score 0):

As a brute force solution, you could add a column to the table: `lockColumn int not null default 0`

At the start of both transactions call `update tab1 set lock = lock + 1 where NonClustInd = whatever`

I don't particularly like this, though, and don't see it as a permanent solution; merely a stopgap while you work out what the permanent solution is.